# Foreman, Rails, Puma SSL/HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https, puma, foreman

How can I combine these two commands so Rails uses the `-b` options in the `puma` command?

```
puma: puma -b 'ssl://127.0.0.1:3000?key=/Users/cdrum/.ssh/server.key&cert=/Users/cdrum/.ssh/server.crt' -b 'tcp://127.0.0.1:3001'
rails: bundle exec rails s --binding=127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -e $RAILS_ENV puma
```

Presently with this I get this error:

```
puma/binder.rb:272:in `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) for"127.0.0.1" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

Alternatively, can I tell `Rails` to look for the `puma` instance already running instead of trying to boot it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually solve this by *solely* running `puma` and storing all the config in `config/puma.rb`. Different cert. management but no matter:

```
threads_count = ENV.fetch('RAILS_MAX_THREADS') { 5 }
threads threads_count, threads_count
port ENV.fetch('PORT') { 3000 }
environment ENV.fetch('RAILS_ENV') { 'development' }
plugin :tmp_restart

localhost_key = "#{Dir.pwd}/#{File.join('config', 'certs', 'localhost.key')}"
localhost_cert = "#{Dir.pwd}/#{File.join('config', 'certs', 'localhost.crt')}"

unless File.exist?(localhost_key)
  def generate_root_cert(root_key) # rubocop:disable Metrics/AbcSize
    root_ca = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new
    root_ca.version = 2
    root_ca.serial = 0x0
    root_ca.subject = OpenSSL::X509::Name.parse '/C=BE/O=A1/OU=A/CN=localhost'
    root_ca.issuer = root_ca.subject
    root_ca.public_key = root_key.public_key
    root_ca.not_before = Time.now
    root_ca.not_after = root_ca.not_before + 2 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60
    root_ca.sign(root_key, OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new)
    root_ca
  end

  root_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(2048)
  file = File.new(localhost_key, 'wb')
  file.write(root_key)
  file.close

  root_cert = generate_root_cert(root_key)
  file = File.new(localhost_cert, 'wb')
  file.write(root_cert)
  file.close
end

ssl_bind '0.0.0.0', '8443', key: localhost_key, cert: localhost_cert
```

Now both HTTP and HTTPS work for my `Rails` app.

`Procfile` is now just:

```
web: puma
```

You *do* need a [special](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1670#issuecomment-439138076) branch of the `puma` gem though to avoid an SSL error.